# Capistrano: cannot load such file -- rvm/capistrano (LoadError)

Tags: rvm, capistrano

This is really bugging me as there is a bit (not a lot) on the internet about the following error when running `cap deploy:cold`

`cannot load such file -- rvm/capistrano (LoadError)`

The solution *seems* to be `gem install rvm-capistrano`. Everyone else says installing that gem fixed the error, but for me it does nothing.

The offending lines are:

```
# Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))

# Load RVM's capistrano plugin.    
require "rvm/capistrano"

set :rvm_ruby_string,  ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"")
set :rvm_type, :user
###
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the following line too.

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
```

That, and installing the rvm-capistrano gem solved similar issue for me.